# Snakemake wrappers suddenly stopped working

Tags: python, snakemake

I have this wrappers in my `snakemake` file

```
rule fastqc:
    input:
        "reads/{sample}_trimmed.fq.gz"
    output:
        html="qc/fastqc/{sample}.html",
        zip="qc/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip" # the suffix _fastqc.zip is necessary for multiqc to find the file
    params:
        extra = "--quiet"
    log:
        "logs/fastqc/{sample}.log"
    threads: config["resources"]["fastqc"]["cpu"]
    conda:
        "envs/qc.yaml"
    wrapper:
        "v1.31.1/bio/fastqc"
```

qc.yaml:

```
name: qc
channels: 
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - python
  - fastqc
  - multiqc
```

This normally works, but suddenly it stopped working (I have not changed the code) and I get this error:

```
[Thu Jun  8 15:34:53 2023]
rule fastqc:
    input: reads/S15_trimmed.fq.gz
    output: qc/fastqc/S15.html, qc/fastqc/S15_fastqc.zip
    log: logs/fastqc/S15.log
    jobid: 2
    reason: Missing output files: qc/fastqc/S15_fastqc.zip
    wildcards: sample=S15
    threads: 4
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Thu Jun  8 15:34:53 2023]
rule fastqc:
    input: reads/L8_trimmed.fq.gz
    output: qc/fastqc/L8.html, qc/fastqc/L8_fastqc.zip
    log: logs/fastqc/L8.log
    jobid: 6
    reason: Missing output files: qc/fastqc/L8_fastqc.zip
    wildcards: sample=L8
    threads: 4
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Thu Jun  8 15:34:53 2023]
rule fastqc:
    input: reads/S8_trimmed.fq.gz
    output: qc/fastqc/S8.html, qc/fastqc/S8_fastqc.zip
    log: logs/fastqc/S8.log
    jobid: 4
    reason: Missing output files: qc/fastqc/S8_fastqc.zip
    wildcards: sample=S8
    threads: 4
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

python -c "from __future__ import print_function; import sys, json; print(json.dumps([sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor]))"
Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/32ae7e363cfd65f035e232e794d5bc2b_
python -c "from __future__ import print_function; import sys, json; print(json.dumps([sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor]))"
Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/32ae7e363cfd65f035e232e794d5bc2b_
python -c "from __future__ import print_function; import sys, json; print(json.dumps([sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor]))"
Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/32ae7e363cfd65f035e232e794d5bc2b_
Environment defines Python version < 3.7. Using Python of the main process to execute script. Note that this cannot be avoided, because the script uses data structures from Snakemake which are Python >=3.7 only.
Environment defines Python version < 3.7. Using Python of the main process to execute script. Note that this cannot be avoided, because the script uses data structures from Snakemake which are Python >=3.7 only.
/home/user/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/bin/python3.11 /mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/scripts/tmpx1titff7.wrapper.py
/home/user/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/bin/python3.11 /mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/scripts/tmpw1yrfmqi.wrapper.py
Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/32ae7e363cfd65f035e232e794d5bc2b_
Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/32ae7e363cfd65f035e232e794d5bc2b_
Environment defines Python version < 3.7. Using Python of the main process to execute script. Note that this cannot be avoided, because the script uses data structures from Snakemake which are Python >=3.7 only.
/home/user/mambaforge/envs/snakemake/bin/python3.11 /mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/scripts/tmpnh80ovk0.wrapper.py
Activating conda environment: .snakemake/conda/32ae7e363cfd65f035e232e794d5bc2b_
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/scripts/tmpx1titff7.wrapper.py", line 17, in <module>
    from snakemake_wrapper_utils.snakemake import get_mem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snakemake_wrapper_utils'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/scripts/tmpw1yrfmqi.wrapper.py", line 17, in <module>
    from snakemake_wrapper_utils.snakemake import get_mem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snakemake_wrapper_utils'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/scripts/tmpnh80ovk0.wrapper.py", line 17, in <module>
    from snakemake_wrapper_utils.snakemake import get_mem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snakemake_wrapper_utils'
[Thu Jun  8 15:34:54 2023]
Error in rule fastqc:
    jobid: 4
    input: reads/S8_trimmed.fq.gz
    output: qc/fastqc/S8.html, qc/fastqc/S8_fastqc.zip
    log: logs/fastqc/S8.log (check log file(s) for error details)
    conda-env: /mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/32ae7e363cfd65f035e232e794d5bc2b_

[Thu Jun  8 15:34:54 2023]
Error in rule fastqc:
    jobid: 2
    input: reads/S15_trimmed.fq.gz
    output: qc/fastqc/S15.html, qc/fastqc/S15_fastqc.zip
    log: logs/fastqc/S15.log (check log file(s) for error details)
    conda-env: /mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/32ae7e363cfd65f035e232e794d5bc2b_

[Thu Jun  8 15:34:54 2023]
Error in rule fastqc:
    jobid: 6
    input: reads/L8_trimmed.fq.gz
    output: qc/fastqc/L8.html, qc/fastqc/L8_fastqc.zip
    log: logs/fastqc/L8.log (check log file(s) for error details)
    conda-env: /mnt/4TB_SSD/analyses/CRISPR/test/.snakemake/conda/32ae7e363cfd65f035e232e794d5bc2b_

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

There seems to be a Python version conflict suddenly that cannot be avoided. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how it is possible that it worked before and now it does not work without any changes whatsoever. What snakemake version do you use? What was the snakemake call? Do you run snakemake inside conda environment?

Further, when you use a wrapper, wrapper defines its own environment, therefore you should not define conda in rules using wrapper. Remove it so it would look like this:

```
rule fastqc:
    input:
        "reads/{sample}_trimmed.fq.gz"
    output:
        html="qc/fastqc/{sample}.html",
        zip="qc/fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.zip" # the suffix _fastqc.zip is necessary for multiqc to find the file
    params:
        extra = "--quiet"
    log:
        "logs/fastqc/{sample}.log"
    threads: config["resources"]["fastqc"]["cpu"]
    wrapper:
        "v1.31.1/bio/fastqc"
```

Snakemake will now use the wrapper conda environment instead of the rule environment to run the wrapper code, solving the problem.